# FindAll using Lambda expression in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I'm using lambda expression in LINQ. When i build it shows

'No overload for method FindAll takes 0 arguments'

//Code:

```
        List<Dispatch> lstDispatch = dataLayer.LoadDispatchDetails(val);

       lstDispatch = lstDispatch.FindAll().Where(dispatch => dispatch.InvoiceStatus != "Delivered" && dispatch.IsActive=1);
```

Why?

Comment: I tried that. But, The left hand side of the assignment must be a variable, property or indexer. I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You invoke **FindAll** without any predicate.  It should be something like this

```
var result = lstDispatch.FindAll(dispatch => dispatch.InvoiceStatus != "Delivered" && dispatch.IsActive==1);
```

Comment: I think the last condition should be `dispatch.IsActive == 1`. Anyway, this is the solution. +1

Comment: @SanthoshKumar answerers **commonly** copy your code and modify without noticing that your code is wrong **seriously**. That's why it didn't work for you.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar I just tried to use your variable convention, but obviously i did it wrong. Just use another variable